# How to replace an anchor with its inner html content?

Tags: php, html, regex

Hello how can I replace an anchor with its inner conetent. I mean let's say I have `<a someAttrs>someHtmlContent</a>`   and I want someHtmlContent as output using PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Comment: Can you elaborate more in details; What are you going to do? You can use javascript in client side.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi Well, I have not thought of javascript. I prefer to delever neat HTML to my mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `<a someAttrs>someHtmlContent</a>` you can, use [strip_tags() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp) in php to strips any tag in your string and convert to `someHtmlContent`.

For example:

```
<?php
echo strip_tags("<a someAttrs>someHtmlContent</a>");
?>
```

will gives you desired answer. But if you must first find the anchor tags, please refer to previews answers.

Also you can find documentation of strip_tags function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Answer (score 1):

Would be good to use this library:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

or some of the others mentioned here:
[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)